# What do the Terminal menu item icons under Window mean?

Tags: macos, terminal, menu-bar

Where is terminal app window menu symbology documented as I can't find out what the icons to the left of the existing terminals open under the Window menu mean.

I understand the check mark is the current window in the foreground, but what does the dot mean?

Answer (score 12):

A diamond (♦︎) means the window is minimized (as user3439894 said in their answer). But a dot (•) means the window is "dirty" — that is, it can't be closed without potentially losing something. An app will typically ask for confirmation before closing a dirty window.

These conventions apply across macOS's UI, not just Terminal.

For Terminal, dirty means that there's a program running in the shell, other than the ones listed as safe in Preferences > Profiles pane > Shell tab > Ask before closing.

Answer (score 5):

The diamond icon, (AXMenuItemMarkChar ◆), to the left of the window name in Terminal's Window menu shows that the window is minimized.

[image]